# Use regex to modify specific column names

Tags: r, regex

I want to rename the columns of a dataframe (**10th** column onwards till the **second last** column). My code did not modify the column names at all.

```
all.lesions <- data.frame(t(apply(all.lesions, 1, unlist)), check.names = FALSE)
colnames(all.lesions[10:ncol(all.lesions)-1]) <- sub('^([^.]+.[^.]+.[^.]+.[^.]+).*', '\\1', colnames(all.lesions[10:ncol(all.lesions)-1]))
colnames(all.lesions[10:ncol(all.lesions)-1]) <- substring(colnames(all.lesions[10:ncol(all.lesions)-1]), 1, nchar(colnames(all.lesions[10:ncol(all.lesions)-1]))-1)
```

Input:

```
> dput(all.lesions[1:2,c(9:16,length(colnames(all.lesions)))])
structure(list(Amplitude.Threshold = c("0: t<0.1; 1: 0.1<t< 0.9; 2: t>0.9", 
"0: t<0.1; 1: 0.1<t< 0.9; 2: t>0.9"), TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A.11D.A381.01 = c(0, 
0), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A.11D.A381.01 = c(0, 0), TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A.11D.A381.01 = c(0, 
0), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A.12D.A381.01 = c(0, 0), TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A.21D.A381.01 = c(1, 
1), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A.11D.A381.01 = c(0, 0), TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A.11D.A381.01 = c(0, 
0), X = c(NA, NA)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

> dput(names(all.lesions)[10:ncol(all.lesions)])
c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A.11D.A381.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A.11D.A381.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A.11D.A381.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A.12D.A381.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A.21D.A381.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A.11D.A381.01"
"X")

> class(all.lesions)
[1] "data.frame"
> typeof(all.lesions)
[1] "list"
```

Expected output:

```
[1] "TCGA.2K.A9WE.01"
[3] "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01"
[5] "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01"
```

Comment: first your data only has 5 columns. Consider using the dput of `dput(names(all.lesions)[10:ncol(all.lesions)])` notice you are only interested in the columnnames So no need of the data, just the necessary column names

Comment: I've seen this question all over, why isn't it marked as a Duplicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
This should work:

```
# colnames vector
x <- colnames(all.lesions)[10:(ncol(all.lesions) - 1)] 
# do the regex
sub("^(\\w+\\.\\w+\\.\\w+\\.\\w+)\\..*", "\\1", x)
# use setNames
setNames(all.lesions)[10:(ncol(all.lesions) - 1)], x)
```

Here is solution using 5 column names as vector and applying `sub` with the regex:
After changing the vector of column names we could use ?`setNames(object = nm, nm)` to rename the column names.

```
all.lesions <- x[1:5]

sub("^(\\w+\\.\\w+\\.\\w+\\.\\w*)\\A.*", "\\1", all.lesions)
```

```
[1] "TCGA.2K.A9WE.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01"
[3] "TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01"
[5] "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01"
```

Comment: `sub("(TCGA\\..{2}\\..{4}\\.[0-9]{2})(.)*","\\1", colnames(all.lesions[10:(length(colnames(all.lesions))-1)]))` by itself works as expected but not when assigned to the dataframe `colnames(all.lesions[10:(length(colnames(all.lesions))-1)]) <- sub("(TCGA\\..{2}\\..{4}\\.[0-9]{2})(.)*","\\1", colnames(all.lesions[10:(length(colnames(all.lesions))-1)]))`

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @Anon that's not how you call that, `colnames(all.lesions)=sub(...,colnames(all.lesions))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A.11D.A381.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A.11D.A381.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A.11D.A381.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A.12D.A381.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A.21D.A381.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A.11D.A381.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A.11D.A381.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A.11D.A42I.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J9.01A.11D.A42I.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A.11D.A42I.01", 
"X", "TCGA", "columns")
```

x are your column names

```
> sub("(TCGA\\..{2}\\..{4}\\.[0-9]{2})(.)*","\\1",x)
 [1] "TCGA.2K.A9WE.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01"
 [6] "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9J9.01" "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01"
[11] "X"               "TCGA"            "columns"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected output it seems that you **always** want to cut the column names to the first 15 chars. Based on this premise you can use `rename_with`thus:

```
libraryr(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  rename_with(., ~str_extract(., ".{15}"))
```

Obviously, the pattern you feed into `str_extract`can be varied to allow for a more varied structure of the strings. For example, if the **rule** is that you want to set the cut between "01" and "A", then you can reformulate the pattern thus, using positive look-behind `(?=...)`:

```
df %>%
  rename_with(., ~str_extract(., ".*01(?=[A-Z])"))
```

Alternatively, this works too, where the pattern `(\\w+\\.)`, which matches one or more letters or digits followed by a dot, is repeated three times before "01":

```
df %>%
  rename_with(., ~str_extract(., "(\\w+\\.){3}01"))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A.11D.A381.01 = NA,
  TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A.11D.A381.01 = NA,
  TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A.11D.A381.01 = NA, 
  TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A.12D.A381.01 = NA)
```

Answer (score -1):

without using regex this is a potential script I utilize to modify column names (put the column index you wish, here I'm changing the 2nd and 3rd):

```
df <- data.frame(1:10,11:20, 21:30)
colnames(df)[c(2:3)]<-c('name1','name2')
df
```

Hope it helps!